# Expression Evaluation using combinators in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, evaluation

I'm trying to make an expression evaluator in Hakell:

```
data Parser i o
  = Success o [i]
  | Failure String [i]
  | Parser
      {parse :: [i] -> Parser i o}

data Operator = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | Pow

data Expr
  = Op Operator Expr Expr
  | Val Double

expr :: Parser Char Expr
expr = add_sub
  where
    add_sub =  calc Add '+' mul_div  <|>  calc Sub '-' mul_div  <|>  mul_div
    mul_div =  calc Mul '*' pow  <|>  calc Div '/' pow  <|>  pow
    pow     =  calc Pow '^' factor  <|>  factor
    factor  =  parens  <|>  val
    val     =  Val  <$>  parseDouble
    parens  =  parseChar '('  *>  expr  <*  parseChar ')'
    calc c o p =  Op c  <$>  (p  <*  parseChar o)  <*>  p
```

My problem is that when I try to evaluate an expression with two operators with same priority (e.g. `1+1-1`) the parser will fail.

How can I say that an `add_sub` can be an operation between two other `add_sub`s without creating an infinite loop?

Comment: have you tried `add_sub =  calc Add '+' add_sub  <|>  calc Sub '-' add_sub  <|>  mul_div`? and similarly, `mul_div =  calc Mul '*' mul_div  <|>  calc Div '/' mul_div  <|>  pow` etc.

Comment: (I'm assuming a LL parser combinator like parsec here. If it's something else more powerful I might be wrong here) `calc` uses `p` exactly twice. Also it's the same `p` we get something like (pseudo-code) `addsub = muldiv + muldiv | ....` instead of `addsub = muldiv + addsub | ...` . This is not the only issue: your grammar is not LL, since e.g. `muldiv + .... | muldiv - ... | ...` can not be handled in LL since both options start with the same prefix -- you should probably refactor your grammar.

Comment: @WillNess I have tried this, it creates an infinite loop

Comment: what is the definition of `Parser`? and `Expr`?

Comment: @chi thanks this explains it, i changed the second `p` to `expr` in the definition of calc and it seems to have fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @chi the problem is that `calc` was using p twice which doesn't allow for patterns like `muldiv + .... | muldiv - ... | ...`

I just changed the definition of `calc` to :

```
calc c o p p2 = Op c <$> (p <* parseChar o) <*> p2
```

where p2 is the current priority (`mul_div` in the definition of `mul_div`)

it works much better but the order of calulations is backwards:
`2/3/4` is parsed as `2/(3/4)` instead of `(2/3)/4`

Comment: There are several things to test, but one is ensuring that `1-2+3` is not parsed as `1-(2+3)`. This is a common problem of many grammars. Your solution might not be completely correct.

Comment: It seems your grammar would have productions like `add_sub ::=  mul_div + expr` and `mul_div ::= pow * expr`. This doesn't look correct at all.

Comment: after running some more tests, this is definitely not correct, however I'm not sure what I can do to fix it, do i have to rethink `eval` completely or is there a simple solution I'm missing?